# Add new option to existing product attribute

Tags: attributes, products, setup-script, attribute-options

I am trying to use the function `addAttributeOption` to add a new option to an attribute. I do not want to change the current option order or defaults but simply want to append a new option to the end of the list.

Firstly I tried to get all the options on the attribute and simply append the new one as follows.

```
$attributeModel->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

But then it complains about the lack of default value. Ideally I do not want to have to reformat the array returned from `getAllOptions` as it only returns `value` and `label`.

Comment: strange that peploes downvoted for you too :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I was being silly. The function `addAttributeOption` allows you to add and update options.

To add a new option you simply need an array with the following format.

```
$option['attribute_id'] = $attributeId;
$option['value'][]      = $storeValues;
```

Where `$storeValues` is simply an array where the key is the store id and the value is the value you want for that store.

Then by calling `$installer->addAttributeOption($option);` your new option will be added.

To update an option you simply need to change your option array to have the option id as the key.

```
$option['attribute_id']     = $attributeId;
$option['value'][$optionId] = $newStoreValues;
```

Answer (score 1):

this works perfect for me

```
$arg_attribute = 'manufacturer';
$arg_value = 'new option to be added';

$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
$attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();

$option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
$option['value']['any_option_name'][0] = $arg_value;

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($option);
```